# How can I update the condition in a function-wrapped while with callback without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, security, while-loop, eval

I would like to define a function which will act as a `while` statement (*with some addons, but for reasons of simplicity, I will show here a basic wrapper*). So with conditions as the first parameter, and the callback to execute at each loop as the second one.

I came at first with this version:

```js
const wrappedWhile = (conditions, callback) => {
  let avoidInfinite = 0;

  while (conditions) {
    callback();
    
    if (avoidInfinite >= 10) {
      console.log('breaking while statement for avoiding infinite loop');
      break;
    }
    
    avoidInfinite++;
  }
};

let i = 0;

wrappedWhile(i < 5, () => {
  console.log('log from callback: i =', i);
  
  if (i >= 5) {
    console.log('the loop continues whereas it should stop');
  }
  
  i++;
});
```

Logically, it is expected to stop when `i >= 5`. But the `conditions` parameter is a simple boolean in the `wrappedWhile` function, so it is always `true` as `i` was less than `5` at call.

Then, I came up with another version where `conditions` is evaluated at each iteration of the loop:

```js
const wrappedWhile = (conditions, callback) => {
  while (Function('return ' + conditions + ';')()) {
    callback();
  }
};

let i = 0;

wrappedWhile('i < 5', () => {
  console.log('log from callback: i =', i);
  i++;
});
```

But, if I am not wrong, `Function` is using `eval()` in order to work, and all of us once heard that the usage of `eval()` is not really safe towards code injection.

Now my question is simple: **are there more secure alternatives to do what I want to achieve?**

After some researches, I found a [link](https://blog.risingstack.com/writing-a-javascript-framework-sandboxed-code-evaluation/) which shows a way to *evalify* in a sandbox environment, but I don't know if it is good way or not.

Comment: Are you able to pass the function `() => i < 5`? You’re passing another function, after all…

Comment: Thanks, it is working (as wanjas showed in his answer). It is a bit different from the `while` syntax but I guess it will be good enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a function as a condition and call it in the while loop

```js
const wrappedWhile = (conditions, callback) => {
  let i = 0;

  while (conditions(i)) {
    callback(i);
    
    if (i >= 10) {
      console.log('breaking while statement for avoiding infinite loop');
      break;
    }
    
    i++;
  }
};

wrappedWhile((i) => (i < 5), (iteration) => {
  console.log('log from callback: i =', iteration);
});
```

Comment: `i` has not to be inside `wrappedWhile()` because the condition could involved other variables, but it is working. I suggested an edit of your snippet. Thanks for you answer!